# Does (Old) Armenian have examples of ձ / զ (dz / z) alteration?

Tags: armenian

Does (Old) Armenian have examples of ձ / զ (dz / z) alteration?

Answer (score 2):

I can’t find one, but it is hard to say that it never ever happened, without an exhaustive search.

(“Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence.”)

Etymologically ձ evolved from a few different sounds, maybe depending on the position.  Note that the modern pronunciation is more like `dz`, even though linguists use `j`.

I found [an example of alteration with ծ](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D5%B1%D5%B8%D6%82%D5%A1%D5%B1%D5%A5%D5%B2#) (`ts` one letter) and [with դզ](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D5%A4%D5%A6%D5%AB#Old_Armenian) (`dz` two letters).

My gut says ձ and զ are relatively distinct, and that we may not know the ancient pronunciation of ձ, but that it is more like a palatalisation of or cluster with initial դ.